# How to push data into a "JSON" data type column in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have the following POSTGRESQL table

```
 id | name |    email     | weightsovertime |         joined          
 20 | Le   | le@gmail.com | []              | 2018-06-09 03:17:56.718
```

I would like to know how to push data (JSON object or just object) into the weightsovertime array.

And since I am making a back-end server, I would like to know the KnexJS query that does this.

I tried the following syntax but it does not work

```
update tableName set weightsovertime = array_append(weightsovertime,{"weight":55,"date":"2/3/96"}) where id = 20;
```

Thank you

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who happens to land on this question, the solution using Knex.js is:

```js
knex('table')
      .where('id', id)
      .update({
        arrayColumn: knex.raw(`arrayColumn || ?::jsonb`, JSON.stringify(arrayToAppend))
})
```

This will produce a query like:

```sql
update tableName 
  set weightsovertime = arrayColumn || $1::json
where id = 20;
```

Where `$1` will be replaced by the value of `JSON.stringfy(arrayToAppend)`. Note that this conversion is obligatory because of a [limitation of the Postegre drive](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1519)

Answer (score 0):

`array_append` is for native [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) - a JSON array inside a `jsonb` column is something different.

Assuming your `weightsovertime` is a `jsonb` (or `json`)  you have to use the [concatenation operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) : `||`

e.g:

```
update the_table
  set weitghtsovertime = weightsovertime||'[{"weight": 55, "date": "1996-03-02"}]'
where id = 20;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/XBA24609

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I would manipulate them in my server?

Comment: @user545871: what do you mean with "in my server"? That statement ***is*** run on the (Postgres) server.

Comment: I’m building a backend server that needs access to the database using tool such as knex.js

Comment: @user545871: I don't understand. Can't this knex things just run a SQL statement?